# Change Spinner Text content programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner, and I want to find a way to change the dropdown for my spinner. I want to change my text content through code, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is the structure of my Spinner:

```
val adapter: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        context,
                                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, units1[i]
                                    )
                                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
                                    val new_spin = Spinner(context)
                                    new_spin.setAdapter(adapter)
```

I want to change the text in my spinner to a different list (unit2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the list your adapter is showing you can use `clear` and `addAll` to change the data.

For this case you will want to make sure not to pass the list in to the
constructor of the adapter, otherwise calling `clear` or `addAll` will attempt to modify the original list. If the original
list is immutable (`listOf`) it will throw an error, and if it is mutable (`ArrayList`) you may get unexpected behavior
since it will modify the original source list.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private val arr1 = listOf("1","2","3")
    private val arr2 = listOf("a","b","c")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // If you pass an array in here, calling things like "clear"
        // or "addAll" will modify the original list passed in. Passing in
        // nothing means the adapter will hold its own unique list...
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_spinner_item)

        // ...and you can initialize the adapter's list using addAll
        adapter.addAll(arr1)

        binding.mySpinner.adapter = adapter

        binding.changeSpinnerText.setOnClickListener {
            // to change what is shown, clear the adapter's list
            // and add the new values to show

            adapter.clear() // remove the existing values
            adapter.addAll(arr2) // add the new values
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional statements and populate the array being used in spinner as per the condition then you can set the contents of the dropdown as per your demand.